# how to open an instance of IE in foreground as a vagrant provisionning

Tags: python, powershell, vagrant

I'm launching IE using vagrant, it gets launched as a background process, here is the python code :

```
import pyautogui import webbrowser import time import psutil

while True:

    url = "http://google.com"
    wb = webbrowser.get("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")
    wb.open(url, new=2)
```

Is there a way using powershell or python to open an instance of IE in foreground ?

Comment: Does it have to be a visual GUI through IE based on your business need? Or could you make calls to the resource(s) you need with `Invoke-WebRequest` and go from there?

Comment: IE has to be a  a visual GUI